# codeigniter database error in selecting data

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with selecting data from my database. It show me following error

```
 A Database Error Occurred

 Error Number: 1054

 Unknown column 'BA' in 'where clause'

 SELECT * FROM crime_details INNER JOIN crime_slink ON crime_slink.report_ID =crime_details.report_ID INNER JOIN crime_suspect ON crime_suspect.id=crime_slink.suspect_id INNER JOIN crime_vlink ON crime_vlink.report_ID=crime_details.report_ID INNER JOIN crime_victim ON crime_victim.id=crime_vlink.victim_id WHERE crime_details.report_ID =BA-12-00002

 Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\CNPPO\system\database\DB_driver.php

 Line Number: 330
```

It seems like the problem is in this part  `WHERE crime_details.report_ID =BA-12-00002`
I think the problem was caused by the dashes or hyphens in my query.
Im using `$this->db-query()` function of codeigniter for my queries.

Comment: I believe you need quotes around `BA-12-00002`

Comment: WHERE crime_details.report_ID = 'BA-12-00002'

Comment: What is your active record "where" condition please post here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crime_details.report_ID` holds a `VARCHAR`, so your where condition should be

```
WHERE crime_details.report_ID = 'BA-12-00002'
```

i.e., you need to wrap the value in quotes.

Also, instead of using `$this->db->query()` to run your hand-written MySQL query, you should use ActiveRecord's query builder which would have taken care of this for you. For example, you could have done:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('crime_reports', array( 'report_ID' => 'BA-12-00002' ));
```

Comment: Or just use PDO and keep the queries out of CI

Comment: @AlienWebguy in which case why use an MVC framework altogether?

Comment: No that's a bad assimilation. MVC frameworks are there to organize code and speed up development time. They offer tried-and-tested libraries so devs can spend time building sites and less time writing form validators and whatnot. That being said, PDO > CI's active record. It's just as good at reducing verbosity and follows a better OOP standard, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
WHERE crime_details.report_ID =BA-12-00002
```

to

```
WHERE crime_details.report_ID = "BA-12-00002"
```